# $\sqrt {-i}$ by De Moivre's Theorem

Tags: trigonometry, complex-numbers

$\sqrt{-i} = \left(\cos(\frac{-\pi}{2})+i\sin(\frac{-\pi}{2})\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}$

according to De Moivre's Theorem
 $\sqrt{-i} = \left(\cos(\frac{-\pi}{2})+i\sin(\frac{-\pi}{2})\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}$

$\sqrt{-i} = \left(\cos(\frac{-\pi}{4})+i\sin(\frac{-\pi}{4})\right)$

$\sqrt{-i} = \frac{1-i}{\sqrt{2}}$

similarly ,

$\sqrt{-i} = \left(\cos(\frac{3\pi}{2})+i\sin(\frac{3\pi}
{2})\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}$

$\sqrt{-i} = \left(\cos(\frac{3\pi}{4})+i\sin(\frac{3\pi}{4})\right)$

$\sqrt{-i} = \frac{i-1}{\sqrt{2}}$
why there is two different answer ?

Comment: Generally there are two square roots

Comment: what about $\sqrt{i}$ it does it has two equals roots

Comment: As [Arthur](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/15500/arthur) indicated in his answer, take a square root of $i$ and multiply by $-1$ and you should get a different square root of $i$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get two answers because each complex number (except $0$) has two complex square roots. Note that one is the negative of the other. Thus squaring either of them gives the same result. Which one of them deserves to go under the name $\sqrt{-i}$, as which is forced to make do with $-\sqrt{-i}$ is more or less up to you.

That being said, I advise you to get away from using $\sqrt{\phantom 5}$ when dealing with complex numbers as soon as possible. The utility of the root symbol is not worth the confusions it can lead to.

Answer (score 0):

Oh, so we have $$(-i)^{1/2}=\left(\cos(-π/2+2πk)+i\sin(-π/2 + 2πk)\right)^{1/2}.$$ When you consider the periodicity of the trigonometric functions, it should be apparent why sometimes some powers of some complex numbers are not unique.

So also in this case. By the way, it may be less confusing to apply the symbol $\sqrt{}$ only to nonnegative real arguments, and use powers for other arguments.

Comment: OP was talking about $-i$

Comment: @Arthur Oh, unless I'm mistaken, I thought it was $i$ before it was edited.

Comment: @J.W.Tanner I thought I saw $i.$ Will correct now. Thanks.

Comment: @Allawonder You're right; the original did write $\sqrt i$ in the calculations. Although it seems to have had $\sqrt{-i}$ in the title all along.

Comment: @Allawonder:  I now see in the editing history it was originally $i$ and OP changed it to $-i$